# Could the [grc-framework] tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

Point is that it has 4 answers, one of them referring to the GNU Radio companion. GNU Radio is probably currently a bit famous, yielding to much interest in the GNU Radio Companion, which is commonly referred to as *GRC*, but never "grc framework" or the like. (GNU Radio is a framework, and has its own tag).

Since the [grc-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grc-framework) tag doesn't seem to pose a benefit, and since it seems to start to get confused with GNU Radio Companion (I'm about to propose a new tag for that), I thought a deletion would make sense.

EDIT: Retagged the GNU Radio question as [gnuradio-companion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnuradio-companion), so it's only three questions for [grc-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grc-framework) now.

Comment: It has been removed in the meantime.

Comment: @BhargavRao Thank you! I'll then go and delete this question :)

Comment: Don't, it'll help us track in case the tag is re-created.

Comment: @BhargavRao So, I'll self-answer it as "has been removed" and accept that answer?

Comment: It doesn't actually matter ... adding the [status] tag prevents it from being bumped, which is why I added it. :)